# Looping through XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I'm trying to loop through nodes and check the InnerText to determine if they contain a keyword. I had this working in WPF, but I'm new to using UWP and this is giving me a headache. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm currently only getting HERE: 0 so I know it starts the foreach loop. There is about 100 nodes that should show up.

In WPF, I used this which worked fine:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
```

Attempting this in UWP which isn't working:

```
foreach (IXmlNode node in nodeList)
```

Here's the part of my code I'm having troubles with:

```cs
var doc = new XmlDocument();

StorageFile tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("weatheralerts.xml");
                    String datas = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(tempFile);

doc.LoadXml(datas);

var nodeList = doc.SelectNodesNS("/ns:feed/ns:entry", "xmlns:ns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'");

var x = 0;

foreach (IXmlNode node in nodeList)
{
   Data1.Text = "HERE: " + x;
   x++;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the XML data but if you use the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` type instead of `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument`, you should be able to use the same code like you did in WPF.

Comment: The XML is massive in definition. The main issue I have when using System.Xml is I get this error:

'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no accessible extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I get that from this code:

System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/ns:feed/ns:entry", ns);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` instead of a `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument`, you should be able to use the `SelectNodes` method with an `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

StorageFile tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("weatheralerts.xml");
String datas = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(tempFile);

doc.LoadXml(datas);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/ns:feed/ns:entry", nsmgr);

var x = 0;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Data1.Text = "HERE: " + x;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: `'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no accessible extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @RogerJohnson: You need to target the Fall Creators Update (Build 16299) or later.